# Prevent React Router from accessing directly an URL without navigating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a small game interface that consists of different pages (start menu, loading screen, etc).

Of course I don't want the user to be able to navigate between those pages just by changing the URL in the address bar.
Is there a way to ignore / reject user input from the address bar and just navigate the pages from within the code?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: I came up with an idea that might solve an issue; writing a codesandbox example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by the following steps:

- Create a context where I store the `lastVisitedLocation`, this value is edited when a user taps a link. (We can update it from anywhere in the app!)
- The context exposes also a `registerLocation` function that changes the previous value.

```
const LocationContext = React.createContext(null);

function LocationContextProvider({ children }) {
  const lastVisitedLocation = React.useRef(null);
  function registerLocation(location) {
    lastVisitedLocation.current = location;
  }
  return (
    <LocationContext.Provider value={{ registerLocation, lastVisitedLocation }}>
      {children}
    </LocationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

- Wrap the `Link` from `react-router-dom` and change the `lastVisitedLocation` whenever we tap a Link.

```
const MySpecialLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { registerLocation } = React.useContext(LocationContext);
  return (
    <Link onClick={() => registerLocation(props.to)} ref={ref} {...props} />
  );
});
```

- Create a hook that verify that the user has previously navigated in the app, and that we are not in an allowed route. If we detect a direct access via URL, throw an Error (we can basically implement any desired behavior).

```
const PUBLIC_ALLOWED_ROUTES = ["/home", "/"];

function useInvalidUrlAccess() {
  const currentLocation = useLocation();
  const { lastVisitedLocation } = React.useContext(LocationContext);
  if (
    lastVisitedLocation.current === null &&
    !PUBLIC_ALLOWED_ROUTES.includes(currentLocation.pathname)
  ) {
    throw new Error("Cannot come here directly, buddy");
  }
}
```

- Wrap your `Switch` in the `LocationContextProvider`.

```
    <LocationContextProvider>
      <MySpecialLink to="/">Home</MySpecialLink>
      <br />
      <MySpecialLink to="/page1">Page 1</MySpecialLink>
      <br />
      <MySpecialLink to="/page2">Page 2</MySpecialLink>
      <br />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <HomePage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/page1">
          <Page1 />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/page2">
          <Page2 />
        </Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </LocationContextProvider>
```

- Protect your components by calling the hook in the function's top level

```
function HomePage() {
  useInvalidUrlRoutes();
  return "This is the content of HOME the page";
}
function Page1() {
  useInvalidUrlRoutes();
  return "This is the content of the page 1";
}
function Page2() {
  useInvalidUrlRoutes();
  return "This is the content of the page 2";
}
function NotFound() {
  return "You hit the wrong road, buddy!";
}
```

Finally, here is a [working codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cori-bh1do). I used the `throw new Error` for instance to mark a route as non navigable directly, but basically you can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the browser from opening the entered URL in the URL bar.

You can have a flag in the app state that shows whether the current session is initiated from the home page and set it to `true` only on the home page component. Then you can add the following condition to the page components that you want to limit access to: if the flag is `true`, then the page might be opened, otherwise make a redirection to the home page.

Be aware that it won't be possible to reload the pages with limited access because of the implemented restrictions.

PS: It's a pretty confusing requirement that breaks the way that the web works.
What's the reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect all Urls to your main page.

```
import {
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

     <Redirect from={`${match.url}/`} to={`${match.url}/mainpage`} />
```

Comment: This will prevent any other page from opening programmatically because of the redirects will send the users to the main page.